# How to get response of HttpRequest in case of exception using leaf.xnet

Tags: c#, vb.net

I want to know how to get the actual response in case of exception like if I log in with the correct account it shows the response but in case of incorrect login, it only throws an exception instead of the actual response that the server sends. is there any way to get the actual response if there exists an exception

```
 Try
        Using HttpRequest As New HttpRequest
            HttpRequest.SslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12
            HttpRequest.Cookies = New CookieStorage(False)
            HttpRequest.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json")
            HttpRequest.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
            HttpRequest.UserAgent = "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 10; Android SDK built for x86 Build/QSR1.200403.001)"
            Dim str1 as string = HttpRequest.POST("Google.com").tostring
            TextBox3.Text = HttpRequest.ToString


        End Using

    Catch ex As HttpException
        TextBox3.Text = ex.Message

    End Try
```

The above code `TextBox3.Text = ex.Message` gives the exception message like an error on the client-side etc but not the actual response from the server.

Comment: Which line in the e code throws the exception?

Comment: Chetan Ranpariya
Dim str1 as string = HttpRequest.POST("Google.com").tostring

Comment: What's the exact exception message you are getting?

Comment: The error on the client side. Status code: 404. If I enter bad credential

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya but the server send this response 
USER NOT FOUND OR WRONG PASSWORD!
I want to get this response

Comment: `USER NOT FOUND OR WRONG PASSWORD! I` where do you see this error? Is this a web application or Windows Form Application? Which version of .NET Framework you are using?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya This is a web-based application I'm using .NET Framework 4.5

Answer (score 0):

i know!. you need to instantiate a httprequest objectoutside (ex: http) try-catch  and in catch: you use HttpRequest.Response.ToString (in your case)